# How to change the camera field of View in unity via script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I have an issue I want the camera to zoom in a little when my character runs so how can I change the camera field of view with script when a button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

You can access the main camera field of view like this  `Camera.main.fieldOfView` and then use  `Mathf.MoveTowards` to change the camera field of view over time instead of instantly, set the value that you want your field of view to change to    in `DestFov`

```
public float speed = 5.0;
public float DestFov=50.0;

 void Start () {
     fov = Camera.main.fieldOfView;
 }

 void Update () {
      Camera.main.fieldOfView = Mathf.MoveTowards(Camera.main.fieldOfView, DestFov, Time.deltaTime * speed);
 }
```